# Can we use RTTI to find functions/procedures by name and run them?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-xe3

As we can find a `Property` or an `Object` using `RTTI`, can we search for a certain `function` or `procedure` (not from an object as a `method` but from an `unit`) loaded in memory knowing just it's name?

And if we can, is it possible to execute it sending it's parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi's RTTI system is based around types. However, procedures and functions with unit scope are not associated with types and so cannot be reached using RTTI.

Comment: @SirRufo showed me: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/Event_RTTI_Invocation_(Delphi). So, the only way is to create those function inside objects for me to 'invoke' them?

Comment: You can also retrieve the method parameters by RTTI http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/fun-with-delphi-rtti-dump-a-trttitype-definition/